# why do we invoke print after importing print_function (in Python 2.6)

Tags: python, import

To get the 3.0 print function we do the following in Python 2.6:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

But to use the function we invoke print() not print_function().  Is this just an inconsistency or is there a good reason for this?

Why not the following:

```
from __future__ import print
```

Comment: Because if it was `print_function()` then we wouldn't need to poke the compiler in the first place, which is what `__future__` imports do.

Comment: Really interesting question. I love it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is \_\_future\_\_ in Python used for and how/when to use it, and how it works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075082/what-is-future-in-python-used-for-and-how-when-to-use-it-and-how-it-works)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The reason is that when you import from `__future__` you're really just setting a flag that tells the interpreter to behave a bit differently than usual -- in the case of `print_function`, the `print()` function is made available in place of the statement. The `__future__` module is thus "special" or "magic" -- it doesn't work like the usual modules.

Comment: There is a module called __future__ on the disk and there's a thing called `print_function` in it, but the actual magic is happening elsewhere.

Comment: Summary: There is such a module, but you don't need to care about it, as the magic is done elsewhere. :)

Comment: Can you *unset* that flag once set?

Answer (score 13):

`print_function` is a `FeatureName` not be confused with the `print` built-in function itself.
It is a feature that is available from the future so that you can use the built-in function that it can provide.

Other Features include:

```
all_feature_names = [
    "nested_scopes",
    "generators",
    "division",
    "absolute_import",
    "with_statement",
    "print_function",
    "unicode_literals",
]
```

There are specific reasons as when you migrate your code to next higher version, your program will remain as such as use the updated feature instead of the `__future__` version. Also if it were function name or the keyword itself, it may cause confusion to the parser.

Answer (score 4):

In Python 3, the keyword `print` has been changed from calling a statement to calling a function.

So instead of saying `print value` you now need to say `print(value)`, or you'll get a `SyntaxError`.

By doing the `import`, this change is effected in Python 2, too, so you can write programs using the same syntax as Python 3 (at least as far as `print` is concerned).

Comment: So why not from __future__ import print?

Comment: @broiyan: Because that would be confusing, as it would look like you imported the name "print" which you don't. `__future__` imports are Magick that change the way Pythons syntax behaves.

Comment: ...another question you have the read all the way through to the very last answer to get a simple explanation; **to get python2 to work with python3 print syntax**.

Answer (score 4):

Simple. print is keyword in Python 2.

So a statement like

```
from somewhere import print
```

would be an automatic SyntaxError in Python 2.

Allowing (hardcoding it in the syntax)

```
from __future__ import print
```

was deemed not worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

**Minimal example**

```
>>> print     # Statement.

>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print     # Function object.
<built-in function print>
>>> print()   # Function call.

>>>
```

As mentioned at: [What is __future__ in Python used for and how/when to use it, and how it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075082/what-is-future-in-python-used-for-and-how-when-to-use-it-and-how-it-works) `from __future__` are magic statements that alter how Python parses code.

`from __future__ import print_function` in particular changes `print` from a statement into a built-in function, as shown in the interactive shell above.

**Why `print(1)` works without `from __future__ import print_function` in Python 2**

Because the:

```
print(1)
```

is parsed as:

```
print (1)
^^^^^ ^^^
1     2
```

1. `print` statement
2. argument

instead of:

```
print( 1 )
^^^^^^ ^ ^
1      2 1
```

1. `print()` function
2. argument

And:

```
assert 1 == (1)
```

as mentioned at: [Python tuple trailing comma syntax rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992559/python-tuple-trailing-comma-syntax-rule)

Answer (score 0):

For completness, all the currently [available](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/__future__.html#module-__future__) features are:

```
+------------------+-------------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------+
|     feature      | optional in | mandatory in |                       effect                       |
+------------------+-------------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------+
| nested_scopes    | 2.1.0b1     |          2.2 | PEP 227: Statically Nested Scopes                  |
| generators       | 2.2.0a1     |          2.3 | PEP 255: Simple Generators                         |
| division         | 2.2.0a2     |          3.0 | PEP 238: Changing the Division Operator            |
| absolute_import  | 2.5.0a1     |          3.0 | PEP 328: Imports: Multi-Line and Absolute/Relative |
| with_statement   | 2.5.0a1     |          2.6 | PEP 343: The “with” Statement                      |
| print_function   | 2.6.0a2     |          3.0 | PEP 3105: Make print a function                    |
| unicode_literals | 2.6.0a2     |          3.0 | PEP 3112: Bytes literals in Python 3000            |
| generator_stop   | 3.5.0b1     |          3.7 | PEP 479: StopIteration handling inside generators  |
| annotations      | 3.7.0b1     |          4.0 | PEP 563: Postponed evaluation of annotations       |
+------------------+-------------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------+
```