# What is __future__ in Python used for and how/when to use it, and how it works

Tags: python, python-2.x

`__future__` frequently appears in Python modules. I do not understand what `__future__` is for and how/when to use it even after reading [the Python's `__future__` doc](http://docs.python.org/library/__future__.html).

Can anyone explain with examples?

A few answers regarding the basic usage of `__future__` I've received seemed correct.

However, I need to understand one more thing regarding how `__future__` works:

The most confusing concept for me is how a current python release includes features for future releases, and how a program using a feature from a future release can be be compiled successfully in the current version of Python.

I am guessing that the current release is packaged with potential features for the future. However, the features are available only by using `__future__` because they are not the current standard. Let me know if I am right.

Comment: This is the original proposal for the future statement.  I found it helpful in understanding why it's there in the first place and so when and how to use it follow naturally.  https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0236/

Comment: A future statement is a directive to the compiler that a particular module should be compiled using syntax or semantics that will be available in a specified future release of Python. The future statement is intended to ease migration to future versions of Python that introduce incompatible changes to the language. It allows use of the new features on a per-module basis before the release in which the feature becomes standard.

Answer (score 521, accepted):

With `__future__` module's inclusion, you can slowly be accustomed to incompatible changes or to such ones introducing new keywords.

E.g., for using context managers, you had to do `from __future__ import with_statement` in 2.5, as the `with` keyword was new and shouldn't be used as variable names any longer. In order to use `with` as a Python keyword in Python 2.5 or older, you will need to use the import from above.

Another example is

```
from __future__ import division
print 8/7  # prints 1.1428571428571428
print 8//7 # prints 1
```

Without the `__future__` stuff, both `print` statements would print `1`.

The internal difference is that without that import, `/` is mapped to the `__div__()` method, while with it, `__truediv__()` is used. (In any case, `//` calls `__floordiv__()`.)

Apropos `print`: `print` becomes a function in 3.x, losing its special property as a keyword. So it is the other way round.

```
>>> print

>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print
<built-in function print>
>>>
```

Comment: don't forget `from __future__ import braces` :p

Comment: @zoogleflatt If you are more of a tab guy, you don't know PEP 8. It is strongly recommended to *not* use tabs...

Comment: @glglgl Well technically it just says they're preferred.  It wasn't entirely clear to me after reading why this is exactly, I'm guessing it's to have indent levels match up exactly to make code neater?

Comment: @zoogleflatt It surely has also to do with the fact that most people use 4 spaces for 1 level of indentation, that for compatibility reasons one tab is equivalent to 8 spaces and mixing tabs and spaces is discouraged (resp., AFAIK, even disallowed in Py3)

Comment: I guess that current python version has to include two methods for /, one is __div__ and the other is __truediv__, when __future__ is imported, the latter is used, otherwise use the former.

Comment: Do I still need __future__ if my python version is 3.7 now? I used it before when my python version was 2.7. Wondering if I can now remove it now that the python version is migrated.

Comment: @whiteSkar I am currently not up to date with newer versions of python 3, but I assume that it is still in use, just that you don't probably need it with these quite old features. In Python 3, `print` is definitely a function, but there may be other features which might use `__future__`. (Edit: see https://docs.python.org/3/library/__future__.html where it is still used.)

Comment: @Acecool A 1MB source file sounds absurdly huge. That said, PEP-8 only strictly applies to code intended for inclusion in the standard library. Otherwise, it's an *example* style guide (though one that has become popular among non-core developers who have no other strong preference). Use whatever style *your* group is comfortable with, but consider who the audience for your code is.

Comment: @whiteSkar As long as you aren't supporting anything older than 3.7, `annotations` is the only feature you might be interesting in using. Everything else is mandatory as of 3.7 and does not require a future import.

Answer (score 246):

When you do

```
from __future__ import whatever
```

You're not actually using an `import` statement, but a [future statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#future-statements). You're reading the wrong docs, as you're not actually importing that module.

Future statements are special -- they change how your Python module is parsed, which is why they **must** be at the top of the file. They give new -- or different -- meaning to words or symbols in your file. From the docs:

> A future statement is a directive to the compiler that a particular module should be compiled using syntax or semantics that will be available in a specified future release of Python. The future statement is intended to ease migration to future versions of Python that introduce incompatible changes to the language. It allows use of the new features on a per-module basis before the release in which the feature becomes standard.

If you actually want to import the `__future__` module, just do

```
import __future__
```

and then access it as usual.

Comment: Technically, it is also an import statement, as the relevant name is bound to a local variable. `from __future__ import print_function` both changes the behavior of the `print` keyword and has a runtime affect equivalent to `print_function = __import__("__future__").print_function`

Answer (score 150):

`__future__` **is a pseudo-module which programmers can use to enable new language features which are not compatible with the current interpreter**. For example, the expression `11/4` currently evaluates to `2`. If the module in which it is executed had enabled true division by executing:

```
from __future__ import division
```

the expression `11/4` would evaluate to `2.75`. By importing the `__future__` module and evaluating its variables, you can see when a new feature was first added to the language and when it will become the default:

```
>>> import __future__
>>> __future__.division
_Feature((2, 2, 0, 'alpha', 2), (3, 0, 0, 'alpha', 0), 8192)
```

Comment: So, based on the release version in the variables, if your interpreter is using a later version than indicate, the `import __future__ xyz` is a no-op?

Comment: It is somewhat analogous to a polyfill in the browser world

Answer (score 74):

There are some great answers already, but none of them address a complete list of what the `__future__` statement currently supports.

Put simply, **the `__future__` statement forces Python interpreters to use newer features of the language.**

---

The features that it currently supports are the following:

### `nested_scopes`

Prior to Python 2.1, the following code would raise a **NameError**:

```
def f():
    ...
    def g(value):
        ...
        return g(value-1) + 1
    ...
```

The `from __future__ import nested_scopes` directive will allow for this feature to be enabled.

### `generators`

Introduced generator functions such as the one below to save state between successive function calls:

```
def fib():
    a, b = 0, 1
    while 1:
       yield b
       a, b = b, a+b
```

### `division`

Classic division is used in Python 2.x versions. Meaning that some division statements return a reasonable approximation of division ("true division") and others return the floor ("floor division"). Starting in Python 3.0, true division is specified by `x/y`, whereas floor division is specified by `x//y`.

The `from __future__ import division` directive forces the use of Python 3.0 style division.

### `absolute_import`

Allows for parenthesis to enclose multiple `import` statements. For example:

```
from Tkinter import (Tk, Frame, Button, Entry, Canvas, Text,
    LEFT, DISABLED, NORMAL, RIDGE, END)
```

Instead of:

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Frame, Button, Entry, Canvas, Text, \
    LEFT, DISABLED, NORMAL, RIDGE, END
```

Or:

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Frame, Button, Entry, Canvas, Text
from Tkinter import LEFT, DISABLED, NORMAL, RIDGE, END
```

### `with_statement`

Adds the statement `with` as a keyword in Python to eliminate the need for `try/finally` statements. Common uses of this are when doing file I/O such as:

```
with open('workfile', 'r') as f:
     read_data = f.read()
```

`print_function`:

Forces the use of Python 3 parenthesis-style `print()` function call instead of the `print MESSAGE` style statement.

`unicode_literals`

Introduces the literal syntax for the `bytes` object. Meaning that statements such as `bytes('Hello world', 'ascii')` can be simply expressed as `b'Hello world'`.

### `generator_stop`

Replaces the use of the `StopIteration` exception used inside generator functions with the `RuntimeError` exception.

One other use not mentioned above is that the `__future__` statement also requires the use of Python 2.1+ interpreters since using an older version will throw a runtime exception.

---

### References

- [https://docs.python.org/2/library/**future**.html](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html)
- [https://docs.python.org/3/library/**future**.html](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__future__.html)
- https://docs.python.org/2.2/whatsnew/node9.html
- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/
- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/
- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/
- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3112/
- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/

Comment: Assuming you are offline how does python know whether a future version is available or not? And how does it use future features if you have not installed future version of python on your computer?

Comment: @MohsenHaddadi The future statement is somewhat like a feature flag... When certain features are accepted into Python that change the behavior of existing programs (like true division, for example), first you are able to enable them with the future statement, and then in a *future* version they become a permanent feature of the language. Hence the name `__future__`. I believe that this ability to opt into breaking changes early is meant to help existing programs transition in a timely manner, before the breaking change is put into full effect.

Comment: I think this is the best answer. especially the start of the answer, "force" to use "newer features".

Comment: Excellent answer, I just wish there was an `from __past__ import print` as I really liked the laziness of Python 2's `print quick_debug_var`

Comment: perfect answer!

Answer (score 66):

It can be used to use features which will appear in newer versions while having an older release of Python.

For example

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
```

will allow you to use `print` as a function:

```
>>> print('# of entries', len(dictionary), file=sys.stderr)
```

Answer (score 29):

Or is it like saying "Since this is python v2.7, use that different 'print' function that has also been added to python v2.7, after it was added in python 3. So my 'print' will no longer be statements (eg print "message" ) but functions (eg, print("message", options). That way when my code is run in python 3, 'print' will not break."

In

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

print_function is the module containing the new implementation of 'print' as per how it is behaving in python v3.

This has more explanation: http://python3porting.com/noconv.html

Answer (score 4):

One of the uses which I found to be very useful is the `print_function` from `__future__` module.

In Python 2.7, I wanted chars from different print statements to be printed on same line without spaces.

It can be done using a comma(",") at the end, but it also appends an extra space.
The above statement when used as :

```
from __future__ import print_function
...
print (v_num,end="")
...
```

This will print the value of `v_num` from each iteration in a single line without spaces.

Answer (score 4):

[`__future__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__future__.html) is a python [module](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html). It was added to avoid confusing existing tools that analyzed import statements and expected to find the modules they’re importing. It was added in version 2.1 so import of [`__future__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__future__.html) will fail if used prior to version 2.1.

Now see this code:

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> division
_Feature((2, 2, 0, 'alpha', 2), (3, 0, 0, 'alpha', 0), 131072)
```

The *division* returned in the format of `_Feature(OptionalRelease, MandatoryRelease, CompilerFlag)`. *OptionalRelease* and *MandatoryRelease* are both 5-tuples in form of:

```
(
 PY_MAJOR_VERSION, # the 2 in 2.1.0a3; an int
 PY_MINOR_VERSION, # the 1; an int
 PY_MICRO_VERSION, # the 0; an int
 PY_RELEASE_LEVEL, # "alpha", "beta", "candidate" or "final"; string
 PY_RELEASE_SERIAL # the 3; an int
)
```

So in our case, OptionalRelease is 2.2.0a2 and MandatoryRelease is 3.0.0a0.

*OptionalRelease* tells us the first release when the feature was accepted.

*MandatoryRelease* predicts when will the feature be part of the language or shows when the feature became part of the language; in releases at or after that, modules no longer need a future statement to use the feature in question, but may continue to use such imports. If *MandatoryRelease* is None then that planned feature is dropped.

*CompilerFlag* is the (bitfield) flag that should be passed in the fourth argument to the built-in function [compile()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile) to enable the feature in dynamically compiled code. This flag is stored in the compiler_flag attribute on _Feature instances.

Answer (score -4):

After Python 3.0 onward, print is no longer just a statement, its a function instead. and is included in PEP 3105.

Also I think the Python 3.0 package has still these special functionality. Lets see its usability through a traditional "Pyramid program" in Python:

```
from __future__ import print_function

class Star(object):
    def __init__(self,count):
        self.count = count

    def start(self):
        for i in range(1,self.count):
            for j in range (i): 
                print('*', end='') # PEP 3105: print As a Function 
            print()

a = Star(5)
a.start()

Output:
*
**
***
****
```

If we use normal print function, we won't be able to achieve the same output, since print() comes with a extra newline. So every time the inner for loop execute, it will print * onto the next line.