# Python Simple Math coming out to 0.0

Tags: python, math

I am learning Python and am having an issue doing simple math...

```
def main():
    coneHeight = 4.5
    coneR = 1.5
    pi = 3.141

    cone = pi * (1/3) * coneHeight * (coneR * coneR)
    print cone

if  __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If someone could tell me what I am doing wrong, that'd be great. Also, is the last line if `__name__` needed? I have no idea what it does but I was it and it worked.

Comment: As for the `__name__` test, see [What does \`if \_\_name\_\_ == "\_\_main\_\_":\` do?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/419163)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing `(1/3)` which will evaluate to `0`. This is because python's integer division (and in fact most programming languages' integer division) will truncate or round-down. Do this instead:

```
def main():
        coneHeight = 4.5
        coneR = 1.5
        pi = 3.141

        cone = pi * (1.0/3) * coneHeight * (coneR * coneR)
        print cone

if  __name__ =='__main__':main()
```

Or you could do:

```
from __future__ import division
def main():
    coneHeight = 4.5
    coneR = 1.5
    pi = 3.141

    cone = pi * (1/3) * coneHeight * (coneR * coneR)  #no need to do 1.0/3 anymore
    print cone

if  __name__ =='__main__':main()
```

As for your second question,

the `__name__` variable is assigned the value `'__main__'` when the script is run directly (from the shell, cmd, bash, etc). Therefore, your script will only run when this .py file is run directly and `main()` will not be called if it is imported by another file.

Comment: I like `from __future__ import division` better: it's Python 3 forward compatible.

Comment: @Evert what does the future import do?

Comment: @SDK4 Please search. E.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075082/what-is-future-in-python-used-for-and-how-when-to-use-it-and-how-it-works

Comment: @Evert, Thank you. I have included it in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're new to python, if you are thinking in using it in future, read this first (spare some time): http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Regarding your question, here's one solution (of many):

```
# https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html
# no need to declare "pi", just use the tools already created
import math

def main():
  cone_height = 4.5
  cone_r = 1.5
  one_third = float(1) / 3

  cone = math.pi * one_third * cone_height * math.pow(cone_r, 2)
  print cone

if  __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```