# Python Flask division error

Tags: python, flask

I need help with my Python Flask application. I'm trying to give a user the result of a division that they specify, but it's not working. When the user submits "5" and "2" for example, it returns "2" instead of "2.5". I have no idea why it would do this.

Below is my code... can anybody figure out why this would happen?

```
from flask import Flask, session, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'wlFw0WP7SrNmAMF1wJaUSjWMTYdTay8EDIA3FPQhbo9c7wQ9rIdQrzJRzcN1o3mp'

@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    [...]
    if request.method == 'POST':
        a = int(request.form['a'])
        b = int(request.form['b'])
        result = a/b
        return render_template('index.html',session=session,result=result)
    return render_template('index.html',session=session)

# Other routes omitted

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python division](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958684/python-division)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 2, dividing an int by another int will perform integer division.

To get around this, you can multiply `a` by `1.0`, converting it to a float, before dividing by b:

```
result = a*1.0/b
```

This should give you the expected `2.5` instead of `2`.

Comment: Or you can initialize a,b=.0,.0 without multiplying by 1.0, in other ords, u should make it as a float

Answer (score 0):

add this line at the beginning of ur source code.

```
from __future__ import division
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075082/what-is-future-in-python-used-for-and-how-when-to-use-it-and-how-it-works

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the version of Python you are using, the results may be different. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282945/python-integer-division-yields-float) for more details. But in a nutshell, it looks like, in order for you to see a float result, you will need convert the numbers into floats first as the below

```
a = float(request.form["a"])
a = float(request.form["b"])
```