# Python2.7: Syntax error while using print sheet values with a script

Tags: python, xlrd, spyder

I'm trying to printout a few cell contents using the XLRD package in Python 2.7 using the Spyder IDE to create a script. I'm seeing a syntax error while using the command **print sheet.cell_value()** on the IDE while it seems to return correct values when used from the windows command prompt. The error message I see is below:

```
print sheet.cell_value(0, col)
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import xlrd

file_name="C:/Users/Documents/Python Learn/1.xlsx" 
workbook=xlrd.open_workbook(file_name)
sheet=workbook.sheet_by_index(0) 
NumberOfRows=sheet.nrows
NumberOfColumns=sheet.ncols
for col in range(sheet.ncols):
    print sheet.cell_value(0, col)
```

Answer (score 2):

You said `from __future__ import print_function`.  That means that `print` is no longer a statement, and `print ...` with no parentheses is invalid syntax.  Just add the parentheses:

```
for col in range(sheet.ncols):
    print(sheet.cell_value(0, col))
```

Comment: I'm not clear if importing a function transforms the 'print' from statement to something else, maybe a method. Could you please elaborate a bit more on this basic or point me to the resource that I can read. Thanks a  lot, it does help to understand the discrepancy for a new learner like me.

Comment: @pythonprogrammersud: The `__future__` module is a special module that changes what valid syntax is.  In this case, yes you could use `print_function`, but it also replaces the `print` statement with a function, so it can no longer be used as a statement, but must be used as a function: with parentheses.  [Further reading](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7075121/5827958).