# Pycharm import RuntimeWarning after updating to 2016.2

Tags: python, import, pycharm

After updating to new version 2016.2, I am getting

```
RuntimeWarning: Parent module 'tests' not found while handling absolute import
  import unittest
RuntimeWarning: Parent module 'tests' not found while handling absolute import
  import datetime as dt
```

'tests' is a package inside my main app package, and I receive these warnings when I try to execute unit tests inside this folder. This issue only came up after updating to 2016.2. Besides the warnings, the remaining code works fine.

Edit: This is a known issue - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20171. They are suggesting to replace utrunner.py in PyCharm installation folder.

Comment: Yep. I have the same behaviour after the switch to 2016.2

Comment: Alright I will open up a ticket to JetBrains.

Comment: For now, I just copied the old utrunner.py into 2016.2 - ~/pycharm-2016.1/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py

Comment: I have the same behavior and it's really annoying!

Comment: @SamKenny - where did you find the "old" utrunner?

Comment: Ok, I've found it here: http://code.metager.de/source/xref/jetbrains/intellij/community/python/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py

Comment: Can you share the ticket link please? (I'm having the same issue and wish to upvote it)

Comment: Replaced the old file (/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py) with the file for download from [youtrack.jetbrains.com](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20171) ([download link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/_persistent/utrunner.py?file=74-332199&c=true)). Works perfectly for me.

Comment: @mircealungu - backups!

Comment: how did this bug get into production

Comment: According to the issue thread, this will be fixed in 2017.1: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20171#comment=27-1821551

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This is a known issue introduced with the 2016.2 release. Progress can be followed on the JetBrains website [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20171). According to this page it is due to be fixed in the 2017.1 release. You can follow the utrunner.py workaround that others have mentioned in the meantime - a copy of this file is attached to the linked ticket.

Comment: Replaced the old file (/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py) with the file for download from [youtrack.jetbrains.com](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20171) ([download link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/_persistent/utrunner.py?file=74-332199&c=true)). Works perfectly for me.

Comment: There was a recent update the called 2016.2.2, which *did not* fix the issue yet...

Comment: This is still not fixed in pycharm-2016.2.3

Comment: This doesn't seem to be fixed in 2016.3, the same warning occurs.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be fixed in 2016.3.1

Comment: Not fixed in 2016.3.2

Comment: I just downloaded and implemented the workaround as per @Bobby 's instructions. Worked for me on Linux Debian Jessie running PyCharm 2016.3.2.  NOTE: at the JetBrains url it states the bug is "obsolete" in PyCharm 2017.1.

Comment: How does this bug get released

Answer (score 36):

The latest recommendation [(Dec. 19, 2016)](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20171) is to put this line at the top of your unit test script:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

Comment: That fixes the problem for me, but I think it's not an official recommendation, as the user mentioning this doesn't seem to be a JetBrains dev. Since this warning turns up even if only doing absolute imports, wouldn't adding that line be an unnecessary piece of code which would need to be removed after their next release?

Comment: It will probably need to be removed at some point in the future, yes.  For more information, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/7075082/584846

Comment: Yeah, my point was that it's really unnecessary in this case, since this particular `__future__` import is only there for fixing a bug in PyCharm. The source code needs no fix, at least in my case. So it seems that following the advice in the accepted answer would be better, since then the source code doesn't need to be touched at all.

Comment: I am in favor of `from __future__ import absolute_import`. If your Python 2.7 code can take it, I prefer to use all the __future__ imports. It would simplify eventual move to Python 3.6.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. Downloading the other `utrunner.py` and replacing the original did not appear to work. Perhaps Pycharm was caching it; I didn't try restarting my machine.

Answer (score 14):

On OS X I've fixed this by replacing

```
Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py
```

with an older version that can be found at 
    http://code.metager.de/source/xref/jetbrains/intellij/community/python/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py

Answer (score 2):

On **Ubuntu 16.04** Bobby's solution also works:

Just replace your local `utrunner.py` file at

```
/usr/local/pycharm-edu-3.0/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py
```

by the one from the Jetbrains website: http://code.metager.de/source/xref/jetbrains/intellij/community/python/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py

Comment: I found mine installed at a different place, however it worked after replacing it with above version -- why did they not rollback? will doing this not make python unstable??

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10 Bobby's solution also works:

Just replace your local utrunner.py file at

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.3\helpers\pycharm
```

with the one from the Jetbrains website: http://code.metager.de/source/xref/jetbrains/intellij/community/python/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py