# Most Pythonic way to print a newline

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, newline, readability

If I need to print a single newline, what is the most Pythonic way to write the `print()` statement? I am teaching someone Python and I want to do it right.

The two ways that I found most likely were:

1) `print("")`

- Pros: Shorter and more simple
- Cons:

  - Might be less readable due to no mention of `\n`
  - Relies on end being a newline, which may not be inherently obvious

2) `print("\n", end = "")`

- Pros: It is obvious what the statement is meant to do
- Cons: Longer. Beginner might not know what the 'end' argument means.

Comment: `print()` is shorter

Comment: As much as I like this question, shouldn't asking for the most "pythonic" way to do something be asked on codereview? This seems opinionated

Comment: @Ryan Usually, yes. In this case, there's simply not enough to review.

Comment: @depperm" I often use `print('')` because it will does the same thing in both Python 2 & 3. `print()` will output `()\n` in Python 2, not just `\n` as in Python 3, so using  `print('')` is more portable.

Comment: @martineau  I don't think that's a good reason to write weird-looking Python 3 code.  If you want to write portable code, you would use `from __future__ import print_function`.

Comment: @martineau: always use `from __future__ import ...` statements when writing code that has to work on 2 & 3. `print_function` is your friend, but not the only one you should use.

Comment: @wim: For new code, sure, but using `from __future__ import` isn't always an option when working on existing code (or when answering questions here where it's unclear what version is being used). In those situations using `print('')` is worth the slightly weird-looking construct IMO.

Comment: @Martijn: What is said in my response to @ wim...

Comment: @martineau: **just refactor that code**. It's not a big change to go from `print ...` to `print(...)`. We did this at Facebook; require that all Python-2 compatible code *must* have those `__future__` imports. We are well on track with replacing all Python 2 code with Python 3 now; all new code is always Python 3. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nRtp9NgtXiA

Comment: @martineau: Python 2.x has been sunsetted. Everyone's supposed to be on 3.x now. Answers should address 3.x. And it's trivial to add `from __future__ import print_function` to migrate old 2.x code, people have been doing it [for the last 8 years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075082/what-is-future-in-python-used-for-and-how-when-to-use-it-and-how-it-works)

Comment: @smci (and everyone else): I wrote that comment about using `print('')` over 2 years ago when many more folks were still using Python 2 — and I totally agree it's not (that) relevant nowadays...

Comment: @martineau: sure but it's high time to delete the comment. People (like me) are still finding this question today using keyword search; it might get used as a dupe target.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Neither.  The usual way would be:

```
print()
```

Answer (score 4):

Most simple and shorter method is :

```
print()
```

Answer (score 3):

Note in Python 2.x printing a newline is a simple as:

```
print
```