# How __future__ imports work under the hood

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, python-internals, compiler-directives

I've been fascinated by the `__future__` module - in particular, its ability to change the way statements are parsed in python.

What's most interesting is how doing something like

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Enables you to use `print` (and not `print_function`, like you would expect any other normal import to do).

I have read [What is __future__ in Python used for and how/when to use it, and how it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075082/what-is-future-in-python-used-for-and-how-when-to-use-it-and-how-it-works) thoroughly and in particular came across a particular line:

> A future statement is a directive to the compiler that a particular
>   module should be compiled using syntax or semantics that will be
>   available in a specified future release of Python.

I would love to know the intricacies of what exactly makes this possible. In particular, how something like

```
from __future__ import division
```

Can enable true division on python2, while

```
from __future__ import barry_as_FLUFL
```

Can enable the `<>` syntax on python3 (what I find most funny is that you have to import a feature from "`__future__`" for backward compatibility).

Anyway, to summarise, I would like to know how the directive is understood and executed by the compiler when `__future__` or its artefacts are imported.

Comment: Because it's *not* a normal import. See https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#future

Comment: @jonrsharpe "_Anyway, to summarise, I would like to know how the directive is understood and executed by the compiler when __future__ or its artefacts are imported._" I have done my research but thanks for the downvote anyway.

Comment: I should've probably changed the title to discourage people with short attention spans from down voting.

Comment: I feel like there is definitely some _meat_ to this question for whatever my opinion is worth.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Those 3 downvoters and 1 close voter would disagree, but whatever, like I said... probably my fault for the initial bad title.

Comment: The `__future__` module has nothing to do with this behavior.

Comment: @user2357112 Can you elaborate.. (in an answer maybe)? The `__future__` import would trigger those various flags, at least, that's what I've understood.

Comment: to me it's like Perl's `use strict` or `use warnings` which change some internal flags which in turn would change the language's behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`from __future__ import print_function` tells the parser to [not treat `print` as a keyword](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.7.13/Parser/parser.c#L142-L160) (leaving it as a name instead). That way the compiler treats it as the function and not a statement.

To track this, the `compiler` struct has a `c_future` field that holds a `PyFutureFeatures` object that tracks which future directives have been enabled. Various parts of the parser and compiler check the flags and alter behaviour.

This is mostly handled in the [`future.c` source file](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.2/Python/future.c), which has a [`future_parse()` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.2/Python/future.c#L60-L125) that checks for `import from` AST objects with the module parameter set to `__future__`, and sets flags based on what is found.

For example, for the `barry_as_FLUFL` 'feature', the parser [refuses `!=` as syntax but accepts `<>` instead](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.2/Parser/parsetok.c#L239-L254):

```c
if (type == NOTEQUAL) {
    if (!(ps->p_flags & CO_FUTURE_BARRY_AS_BDFL) &&
                    strcmp(str, "!=")) {
        PyObject_FREE(str);
        err_ret->error = E_SYNTAX;
        break;
    }
    else if ((ps->p_flags & CO_FUTURE_BARRY_AS_BDFL) &&
                    strcmp(str, "<>")) {
        PyObject_FREE(str);
        err_ret->text = "with Barry as BDFL, use '<>' "
                        "instead of '!='";
        err_ret->error = E_SYNTAX;
        break;
    }
}
```

You can find the other examples by grepping for the `FUTURE_*` flags [listed in `compile.h`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.2/Include/compile.h#L22-L30).

Note that there is a [`__future__` Python module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__future__.html), but it is not directly involved in the parsing and compilation of code; it is merely there to give Python code easy access to metadata about directives (including bitfield values to pass to the `flags` argument of the [`compile()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile)), nothing more.

Comment: I know this already. What I wanted to know how it works under the hood... that was the purpose of this question.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: that's.. rather broad, but I'll see what I can fill in.

Comment: What I find most funny about barry is that he has to come from `__future__` instead of something more sensible like `__past__`. Thanks for the great answer as always.