# Python: Identifying string list with length of 1 vs. string

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my code I have the following:

```
if all(requiredField in submittedFields for requiredField in requiredFields):
    # all required fields in submittedFields exist
else:
    # error handling
```

The goal is to check if a list of strings in `requiredFields` are all present in `submittedFields`

This works fine when `requiredFields` is a list of strings with length > 1.  But, when you have something like

```
requiredFields = ('single element')
```

Then the for loop iterates over each character instead of the string itself.

So my question is, is there a more pythonic means of handling this other than

```
try: 
    requiredFields.sort()
    # requiredFields is a list of strings
except AttributeError:
    # requiredFields is a string list whose length == 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using python sets would be much more efficient:

```
submitted_fields = set(['length', 'width', 'color', 'single element'])
required_fields = set(['width', 'length'])
if submitted_fields >= required_fields:
    # all required fields in submittedFields exist
else:
    # error handling
```

Several optimizations make this fast:

- The hash table implementation of sets ensures a high likelihood of a match before doing a character by character equality test.
- If two strings are identical (the same object in memory), the identity check will bypass a character-by-character equality check.

Note.  It looks like your original problem was with tuple notation.  Steven Rumbalski addressed that very well.  Of course, if you use sets, this becomes a non-issue.

Good luck with your field validation :-)

Comment: -1 care to provide an example? I know it's faster, but you haven't actually answered his question, or provided an alternative.

Comment: Yes, it will be orders of magnitudes faster.

Comment: @SpencerRathbun While not immediately obvious, it does answer the question. Specifically the "is there a more pythonic means of handling this" bit. The question is what one would call an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @ShawnChin True, but I could just as easily say that "a more efficient solution would be to write a function in assembler. This is left as an exercise to the reader..." Which is why I gave him the -1. Since he added an example, I'm changing that to a +1.

Comment: @SpencerRathbun If you had posted that, then it WOULD warrant a -1. >;)

Answer (score 5):

A string enclosed in parenthesis is not a tuple -- it's a string.  To make a one item tuple you need a trailing comma:

```
>>> ('single element') # this is not a tuple, it's a string
'single element'
>>> ('single element',) # note the trailing comma
('single element',)
```

For more info see the wiki on [Tuple Syntax](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TupleSyntax) the Stack Overflow question [Python tuple comma syntax rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992559/python-tuple-comma-syntax-rule).

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the definition

```
requiredFields = ('single element')
```

is actually equivalent to

```
requiredFields = 'single element'
```

To make a single element list, do

```
requiredFields = ['single element']
```

To make a single element tuple, do

```
requiredFields = ('single element',)
```

Comment: If you're going to put just code on a line, indent it four spaces or use the `{}` button rather than using backticks.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should never have `requiredFields = ('single element')` -- if you want a tuple you should write `requiredFields = ('single element',)`.

but assuming you don't have control over your input, the most pythonic way to test is:

```
if isinstance(requiredFields, basestring):
    # requiredFields is a string
else:
    # requiredFields is iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do something like this:

```
required = ['name', 'password']
submitted = ['name', 'email']

for field in required:
    if field not in submitted:
        print field + ' is required'
```