# SQL Error: ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type

Tags: python, sqlite, valueerror

In a program that I am creating I have used this code:

```
sqlcommand2 = "SELECT ChoiceDesc FROM Choices WHERE Choice_ID = (?)"
result2 = c.execute(sqlcommand2, (firstchoice))
```

However when I run this I get the error ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type. In this instance, Choice_ID is an integer, ChoiceDesc is a string and firstchoice is also an integer. How can I fix this?

EDIT: solved the problem by adding a comma after firstchoice in result2

Comment: What's the database that you are using? PostgreSQL?

Comment: I'm using DB Browser for SQLite

Comment: you can refer solution given on below link this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853167/parameter-unsupported-when-inserting-int-in-sqlite/21082534

Comment: Does this answer your question? [parameter unsupported when inserting int in sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853167/parameter-unsupported-when-inserting-int-in-sqlite)