# getting ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type where i tried all datatypes

Tags: python, database, sqlite, function, spyder

I want to store the GST number where it contains numbers and alphabets together into the database as well as the email id but it is showing me `ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type`. Here I tried just the mobile number and it worked perfectly but not in case of GST and email id

```
 import sqlite3


 import re


 def getphonenumber(s):

 phonenumberregex=re.findall(r'\+\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d|\d\d\d\d+-\d\d\d\d\d\d\d|\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d',line)

 if phonenumberregex:

  print(phonenumberregex)     

   return (phonenumberregex)

 def getemailid(s):

    emailidregex=re.findall(r'\S+@\S+',line)

  if emailidregex:

      print(emailidregex)

  return (emailidregex)



 def getgst(s):

 gstregex=re.findall(r'\d{2}[A-Z]{5}\d{4}[A-Z]{1}[A-Z\d]{1}[Z]{1}[A-Z\d]{1}',line)

 if gstregex:

    print(gstregex)  

 return (gstregex)



 with open('yesno.txt') as s:

    amountdata = s.readlines()

 for line in amountdata:

  if line.__contains__('Gst'):     

   c=getgst(s)

  if line.__contains__('Mob'):    

     a=getphonenumber(s)

  if line.__contains__('Email'): 

     b=getemailid(s) 

 s.close()  

 conn = sqlite3.connect('test3.db') 

 c = conn.cursor() 

 def create_table(): 

     c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS RecordTWO (gst STR)') 


 def data_entry(): 

     c.execute("INSERT INTO RecordTWO (GST) VALUES(?)",  (c))  


     conn.commit() 


 create_table() 

 data_entry() 


 def get_posts():

     with conn:

          c.execute("SELECT * FROM RecordTWO")

          print(c.fetchall())

 get_posts()

 print("Table created successfully")
```

I want to store the value of gst where it contains character and number as well as the email id in the database. Also, can someone tell me how to get the output in a tabular format since I am new to python?

Comment: Code formatting.

Comment: Assuming the ValueError raises when executing the insert query, [you are missing a trailing comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853167/parameter-unsupported-when-inserting-int-in-sqlite). Besides that, in `data_entry` your variable `c` contains your cursor (hence you can call `c.execute` without causing an AttributeError), so you are attempting to insert the cursor into your database. The previous value of `c` from `c=getgst(s)` is overwritten when you create the cursor: `c = conn.cursor()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [parameter unsupported when inserting int in sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853167/parameter-unsupported-when-inserting-int-in-sqlite)

Answer (score 2):

You don't say which line is throwing the exception, but I would guess it's this one:

```
     c.execute("INSERT INTO RecordTWO (GST) VALUES(?)",  (c))
```

Exactly what are you trying to insert into the database? Spend a few moments taking a careful look at this line before reading on.  See if you can figure it out.

In case you can't figure it out, you are using the cursor in the variable `c` to try to insert *the cursor itself* into the database.  That is unlikely to do what you want.  You may have assigned a value to the variable `c` using `c=getgst(s)`, but you overwrote this when you created the cursor and assigned that to `c`.

You have fallen into this trap because you have used single-letter names for you variables.  Don't do this.  Go back and give your variables `a`, `b`, `c` and `s` names that better describe the values they hold.  Yes, it's a little bit more typing, but clear names make your code so much easier to read.

Suppose we rename the cursor variable to `db_cursor`.  How much easier is it to spot an error in the line below than in the one above?

```
     db_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO RecordTWO (GST) VALUES(?)",  (db_cursor))
```

There is one other change you will have to make.  When you write `(c)`, or in my example above, `(db_cursor)`, it seems you're trying to make a tuple with a single value in it.  The second parameter of the `execute` method needs to be a tuple (a list will work here too).  However, `(c)` isn't a 1-tuple, it's just an expression in parentheses.  To make it into a tuple, you include a trailing comma before the `)`:

```
     db_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO RecordTWO (GST) VALUES(?)",  (db_cursor,))
```

To get the output in a tabular format, see other questions on this site, for example [Python format tabular output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356501).

Comment: I'm fairly certain, that the ValueError is caused by the second argument to `execute` not being a tuple (because of the missing trailing comma), list or dict. The respective checks in [`pysqlite_statement_bind_parameters`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Modules/_sqlite/statement.c#L206) fail and the [ValueError](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Modules/_sqlite/statement.c#L318) ultimately raises. If the second argument was of a supported type with unsupported content (e.g. `(c,)`), we'd see `sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.`.

Comment: @shmee: agree, answer updated.  I think it's worth spelling out both problems explicitly: if we only asked the OP to add the trailing comma, they might just get back to us saying "I got a different error, it didn't work" or similar.

Comment: @shmee i am still getting the error " InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type." can you please help me man , i also changes the c variable into d where i was storing the value of gst

Comment: @Kartikaggarwal `d` (you really took Luke's advice regarding variable names to heart, didn't you? :P) contains the return value of [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall), which is either `None` if no match is found or a list of strings. Assuming that only one match was found, you'd probably have to pass `(d[0],)` as parameter tuple to `execute`. But without any knowledge about your input file this is pretty much guesswork.