# SQLite python - parameters are of unsupported type

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to insert records into a sqlite database by using the Python sqlite module.

Executing the *INSERT* statement with *executemany()* results into a "parameters are of unsupported type" error.

```
import  sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('food.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS nutritional_values
                (item, calories, total fat, protein)''')
items = [       ('Broccoli Chinese',    22,     0.7,    1.1),
                ('chia seeds',          490,    30.8,   15.6),
                ('blueberries',         57,     0.3,    0.7),]
c.executemany('INSERT INTO nutritional_values VALUES (?,?,?,?)',items)


c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS food_consumption
                (date, item, amount)''')
c.execute('DELETE FROM food_consumption')
consumed = [    ('24/8/2019', 'Broccoli Chinese',    1.5),
                ('24/8/2019', 'chia seeds',          0.35),
                ('24/8/2019', 'blueberries',         0.4),]
c.executemany('INSERT INTO food_consumption VALUES (?,?,?)',consumed)

sql = """SELECT nv.item, nv.calories
         FROM nutritional_values nv
         INNER JOIN food_consumption fc
             ON nv.item = fc.item"""

for row in c.execute(sql):
    print(row)

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS nutrition_consumed
                (var1)''')

for row in c.execute(sql):
    var1 = row[1]*2
    item = [(var1),]
    c.executemany('INSERT INTO nutrition_consumed VALUES (?)', (item),)

for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM nutrition_consumed'):
    print(row)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

gets

```
    c.executemany('INSERT INTO nutrition_consumed VALUES (?)', (item),)
ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type
```

how to parse the var into the table?

Comment: `(item)` should be `(item,)` to make it a tuple.

Comment: okay corrected, but that doesnt change the error

Comment: I said `(item,)` not `(item),`

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853167/parameter-unsupported-when-inserting-int-in-sqlite

Answer (score 2):

Replace `(item),` to `(item, )`. Working code with output is below.

```
import  sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('food.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS nutritional_values
                (item, calories, total fat, protein)''')
items = [       ('Broccoli Chinese',    22,     0.7,    1.1),
                ('chia seeds',          490,    30.8,   15.6),
                ('blueberries',         57,     0.3,    0.7),]
c.executemany('INSERT INTO nutritional_values VALUES (?,?,?,?)',items)


c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS food_consumption
                (date, item, amount)''')
c.execute('DELETE FROM food_consumption')
consumed = [    ('24/8/2019', 'Broccoli Chinese',    1.5),
                ('24/8/2019', 'chia seeds',          0.35),
                ('24/8/2019', 'blueberries',         0.4),]
c.executemany('INSERT INTO food_consumption VALUES (?,?,?)',consumed)

sql = """SELECT nv.item, nv.calories
         FROM nutritional_values nv
         INNER JOIN food_consumption fc
             ON nv.item = fc.item"""

for row in c.execute(sql):
    print(row)

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS nutrition_consumed
                (var1)''')

for row in c.execute(sql):
    var1 = row[1]*2
    item = [(var1),]
    c.executemany('INSERT INTO nutrition_consumed VALUES (?)', (item,))

for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM nutrition_consumed'):
    print(row)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Output:

abhay@abhay-Lenovo-Z51-70:~$ python test.py

('Broccoli Chinese', 22) 
('chia seeds', 490) 
('blueberries', 57) 
(44,)