# FastAPI + sqlite Inserting data to a database

Tags: python-3.x, database, api, sqlite, fastapi

I am new to FastAPI and am playing around to get to know the framework.
I am trying to insert data into my database but I am missing something.

Here's my model:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Article(BaseModel):
    id: int
    title: str
    slug: str
    content: str
    author: str
    date: datetime

class InArticle(BaseModel):
    title: str
    slug: str
    content: str
    author: str
```

and here's the logic

```
@app.post("/articles", response_model=InArticle)
async def create_article(article: InArticle):
    cursor = connexion.cursor()
    article_obj = (InArticle(
        title=article.title,
        slug=article.slug,
        content=article.content,
        author=article.author
    ))
    db_query = """INSERT INTO Article (title, slug, content, author) 
                    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"""
    cursor.execute(db_query, article_obj)
    connexion.close()
    return article
```

I get this error:

```
cursor.execute(db_query, article_obj)
ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [parameter unsupported when inserting int in sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853167/parameter-unsupported-when-inserting-int-in-sqlite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLAlchemy is complaing about you giving it a single `article_obj` - which it has no idea what to do with. If you plan to issue the queries manually (you might want to look at [SQLModel](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/) or using [SQLAlchemy's ORM](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/)), you're going to have to give the parameters separately.

To use the syntax you've given  you should either give the values manually:

```
cursor.execute(db_query, (article.title, article.slug, article.content, article.author))
```

.. or with named parameters instead:

```
db_query = """INSERT INTO Article (title, slug, content, author) 
                VALUES (:title, :slug, :content, :author)"""

# .. which you can then expand automagically
cursor.execute(db_query, **article_obj.dict())
# **article_obj.dict() expands it to title=article_obj.title, ..etc
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the time, the reactivity and the sources. The first method is working and I have now different ways to explore in order to implement it. Thanks again

Comment: After a little understanding I can pass it as a parameter like I did if it's an object;
***article_obj = {
        "title": article.title,
        "slug": article.slug,
        "content": article.content,
        "author": article.author
    }***
or with the cursors.execute method but it takes 2 arguments. So it is
***cursor.execute(db_query, (article.title, article.slug, article.content, article.author))***
Thanks again for your help.
Tom