# extra empty element when removing an element from a tuple

Tags: python, element, tuples

I have a question about the following python outcome.
Suppose I have a tuple :

```
a = ( (1,1), (2,2), (3,3) )
```

I want to remove `(2,2)`, and I'm doing this with the following code:

```
 tuple([x for x in a if x != (2,2)])
```

This works fine, the result is: `( (1,1), (3,3) )`, just as I expect.

But suppose I start from `a = ( (1,1), (2,2) )`

and use the same tuple() command, the result is  `( (1,1), )` while I would expect it to be `((1,1))`

In short

```
>>> a = ( (1,1), (2,2), (3,3) )
>>> tuple([x for x in a if x != (2,2)])
((1, 1), (3, 3))
>>> a = ( (1,1), (2,2) )
>>> tuple([x for x in a if x != (2,2)])
((1, 1),)
```

Why the comma and empty element in the second case? And how do I get rid of it?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992559/python-tuple-comma-syntax-rule

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python uses a trailing comma in case a tuple has only one element:

```
In [21]: type((1,))
Out[21]: tuple
```

from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences):

> A special problem is the construction of tuples containing 0 or 1
>   items: the syntax has some extra quirks to accommodate these. Empty
>   tuples are constructed by an empty pair of parentheses; a tuple with
>   one item is constructed by following a value with a comma (it is not
>   sufficient to enclose a single value in parentheses).

```
>>> empty = ()
>>> singleton = 'hello',    # <-- note trailing comma
>>> len(empty)
0
>>> len(singleton)
1
>>> singleton
('hello',)
```

Answer (score 0):

It indicates a one-element tuple, just to prevent confusion.

`(1,)` is a tuple, while `(1)` is just the number 1 with unnecessary parentheses.