# What do commas in Python 2.X do when declaring a variable?

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I am using some code out of a book for NetSec, but there is one line I cannot figure out. I am knowledgeable of Python 3, but not 2, which is what this book is eccentric upon.

The code is:

```
client,addr = server.accept()
```

To be quite frank, what the hell does this mean? The entire code for the project is here:

```
import socket
import threading

ip = "192.168.0.155"
port = 9999
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server.bind((ip, port))

server.listen(5)

print "* Listening on %s:%d" %(ip,port)

def handle_client(client_socket):

    request = client_socket.recv(1024)
    print "* Received %s" % request
client,addr = server.accept()
    client_socket.send("Received: %s" % request)


client,addr = server.accept()
    client_socket.send("Received: %s" % request)
    client_socket.close()
    for each in request:
        print each

while True:
    client,addr = server.accept()
    print "* Received connection from %s:%d" % (addr[0], addr[1])
    client_handler = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client,))
    client_handler.start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's called **sequence unpacking**. `server.accept()` returns a tuple `(socket, address)`, which is unpacked into the two variables `client` and `addr`.

It's equivalent to

```
temp= server.accept()
client= temp[0]
addr= temp[1]
```

More info in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

Comment: Thanks, @Rawing! Happy holidays, and happy coding.

Comment: Also, what does having the comma after "client" do in:

Comment: client_handler = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client,))

Comment: `(value,)` is the syntax to create a tuple containing the single element `value`.

Answer (score 1):

server.accept() is returning a [tuple](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm), and the values of that tuple are being assigned to client and addr respectively.
A simplified example:

```
> x,y = (1,2)
> print(x)
1
> print(y)
2
```

This is a very common idiom in Python, and I don't think it's any different in Python 3.

---

Edit
Regarding the trailing comma in ...args=(client,))
see here: [Python tuple trailing comma syntax rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992559/python-tuple-comma-syntax-rule)