# tornado server error under HTTPS

Tags: ssl, https, tornado

Ubuntu 14.04 and 12.04 (all tested), 64bit
pip install tornado  (ver 4.1)

`curl -X POST -v -k  https://remote_ip:8080`

Error as below:
```

```
ERROR:tornado.application:Exception in callback (<socket._socketobject object at 0x7fb670a4ad00>, <function null_wrapper at 0x7fb670a05aa0>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 840, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 223, in accept_handler
    callback(connection, address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 225, in _handle_connection
    do_handshake_on_connect=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 470, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return ssl.wrap_socket(socket, **dict(context, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 489, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 243, in __init__
    ciphers)
SSLError: _ssl.c:295: Both the key & certificate files must be specified
```

My server code looks like this:
```

```
import tornado
import tornado.web
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop

class Docker(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.write('1\n')

application = tornado.web.Application(
    handlers=[
        (r'/', Docker),
    ],
    debug=True,
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ssl_options={'certfile': 'certificate.crt',
                 'keyfile': 'privateKey.key'},
    srv = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application, xheaders=True, ssl_options=ssl_options)
    srv.bind(8080)
    srv.start()
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Note that I use openssl to generate the certificate and key file:

`openssl genrsa -out privkey.pem 2048`

`openssl req -new -x509 -key privkey.pem -out cacert.pem -days 1095`

Especially, when I added one key into the ssl_options dict,  cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE, enven more strange error appeared:

File /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/netutil.py:

`return ssl.wrap_socket(socket, **dict(context, **kwargs))`

dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1 2 is required

I'm really desperate to make my tornado app work properly under HTTPS, could you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra comma after the definition of `ssl_options`. This makes `ssl_options` a tuple containing a dictionary, instead of a dictionary (see [Python tuple trailing comma syntax rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992559/python-tuple-comma-syntax-rule)). Remove that and things should work.

Comment: No worries; it's an easy mistake to make and it can be very tricky to find once it's happened.