# Celery Task apply_async behaviours incorrectly

Tags: python, celery

Call the follow code

```
 tasks.update_address_location.apply_async((address_obj.id), countdown = 10)
```

However the task executes immediately on the queue. It workings so must other possibilities I've rules out. Thought someone might have an answer

```
capp = Celery('async', backend='redis://localhost:6379/0',
              broker='redis://localhost:6379/0', include=['app.async.tasks'])

# Optional configuration, see the application user guide.
capp.config_from_object(celeryconfig)
capp.conf.update(
    CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=3600,
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    capp.start()
```

and celery is called as such:

```
celery multi stop worker  -A app.async.celery_app:capp --beat --loglevel=debug --pidfile=celery.pid --logfile=celery.log
```

The output in the celery.log is consistent and successful, but there no delay in there.

Comment: maybe try `...apply_async((address_obj.id,), {}, countdown=10)`

Comment: note the comma after `address_obj.id`

Comment: That seems to have work @scytale

Comment: added as an answer - please accept it if it worked for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [quirk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992559/python-tuple-trailing-comma-syntax-rule)of python - `(x) == x` - a tuple with one element must contain a comma - `(x,)`

Do this:

```
apply_async((address_obj.id,), {}, countdown=10)
```