# non-keyword arg after keyword arg

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't figured out why is this working :

```
T1 = tree.insert("", 'end', text=BO[2],tags = (BO[3]),values=(strftime(" %d-%m-%Y", gmtime()),BO[5],BO[6],BO[7],BO[8]))
```

while this one is not working :

```
T1 = tree.insert("", 'end', text=BO[2],tags = (BO[3]),values=(BO[4]),BO[5],BO[6],BO[7],BO[8]))
```

I get the following error :

> non-keyword arg after keyword arg

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear to me.  What do you think it means?

Comment: that the second arg s not a keyword while it should be

Answer (score 3):

you have an extra parenthesis after BO[4], so it thinks B[5] through BO[8] are arguments to `insert()`, not part of the `values` tuple

`T1 = tree.insert("", 'end', text=BO[2],tags = (BO[3]),values=(BO[4],BO[5],BO[6],BO[7],BO[8]))`

Comment: also, please note that when you are using tuple syntax, you should always leave a trailing comma  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992559/python-tuple-trailing-comma-syntax-rule

Comment: sometimes an extra set of eyes helps, as does a "correct answer" mark :)