# Why is this is showing 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax?

Tags: python, mysql

It is showing an error in SQL syntax:

```
1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
use near '%s' at line 1
```

Code:

```
if(options==2):
    query = ("SELECT Sl_NO,Title,Genre FROM dvdstore WHERE Genre = %s")
    genre_type = raw_input("Enter the type of genre: ")
    print genre_type
    try:
        y=x.execute(query,(genre_type))
        print y 
        for (Sl_NO,Title,Genre) in x:
            print Title

    except Error as error:
        print(error)
```

Comment: Put the `genre_type` before the `query` then put `query = (".... = %s", query)`

Comment: What type is `x`?

Comment: conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',database='dvdstore',user='root',password=' ')
 
x = conn.cursor()

Comment: <class 'mysql.connector.cursor.MySQLCursor'>

Comment: What happens if you use `y=x.execute(query,(genre_type,))` ? Note the trailing comma in the tuple.

Comment: (And see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992559/python-tuple-trailing-comma-syntax-rule)

Comment: Thanks.... It solved my problem..