# redefining list by changing brackets for parentheses and parentheses for brackets

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples, parentheses, brackets

How may I convert the square brackets inside a list into parentheses and the parentheses outside the square brackets into square brackets?

Example:

```
Lst=[([(1,2)],[(1,2),(1,3)]),([(1,4)],[(1,4),(2,3)])]
```

What I would ideally like to have is:

```
Lst=[[((1,2)),((1,2),(1,3))],[((1,4)),((1,4),(2,3))]]
```

because as you may notice, the parentheses in the original list encloses two pairs of brackets, but I want it the other way around, for the brackets to enclose two pairs of parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to convert inner`list` to `tuple` and outer `tuple` back to `list`. You can do this by list comprehension.

```
In [1]: Lst=[([(1,2)],[(1,2),(1,3)]),([(1,4)],[(1,4),(2,3)])]

In [2]: [list(tuple(k) for k in x) for x in (y for y in Lst)]
Out[2]: [[((1, 2),), ((1, 2), (1, 3))], [((1, 4),), ((1, 4), (2, 3))]]
```

Comment: there is no need of the third loop ie `[[tuple(j)] for i in lst for j in i]` will do

Comment: I just have one more question, since there are some terms with double parentheses which look a little weird, for example ((1,2),). Is it possible to take out a pair, and leave it as (1,2) (with just one parentheses)? Thank you.

Comment: `single-element tuples need a trailing comma, but it's optional for multiple-element tuples` If it is a single element tuple a trailing comma will appear. Other wise it will not treat is as a tuple  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992559/what-is-the-syntax-rule-for-having-trailing-commas-in-tuple-definitions) may help