# django get_or_create saves data in parentheses

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am using django's `get_or_create` to save the data into `postgres`. The code works fine but the **itemgrp1hd** field saves as **('Mobile 5010',)** while I have only fed **Mobile 5010**. Can anyone explain why the parentheses & single quotes are appearing when saved in `postgres`.

The code is as below:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def Post_Items_Axios(request):

    data_itemfullhd = request.data['Item Name']
    data_itemgrp1hd = request.data['Item Group1']

    td_items, created = Md_Items.objects.get_or_create(
        cunqid = entity_unqid,
        itemfullhd = data_itemfullhd,
        # defaults = dict(
        #   itemgrp1hd = data_itemgrp1hd,
        #   )
        )

    # type(request.data['Item Group1']) 
    # <class 'str'>
    td_items.itemgrp1hd = data_itemgrp1hd,

    td_items.save()

    data = {'data_itemfullhd': data_itemfullhd}
    return Response(data)
```

Comment: There is a trailing comma at `td_items.itemgrp1hd = data_itemgrp1hd,`, you should remove that. This wraps the value in a singleton tuple.

Comment: The issue is that you have a comma at the end of this line: `td_items.itemgrp1hd = data_itemgrp1hd,`. Python syntax means that that becomes a tuple, which is what you end up saving. You need to remove the comma.

Comment: That solves my problem. Thanks solarissmoke and Willem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must remove the trailing comma at the end of (or around, as I am on mobile) line 15.

Change

```
td_items.itemgrp1hd = data_itemgrp1hd,
td_items.save()
```

To

```
td_items.itemgrp1hd = data_itemgrp1hd
td_items.save()
```

Having a comma at the end tells Python that you want It saved in a tuple.

See this question here for more about trailing commas and tuples.

[What is the syntax rule for having trailing commas in tuple definitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992559/what-is-the-syntax-rule-for-having-trailing-commas-in-tuple-definitions)