# Inconsistency in printing tuples in python

Tags: python

I have just started to learn python and following the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) on tuples, I came across this snippet,

```
>>> empty = ()
>>> singleton = 'hello',    # <-- note trailing comma
>>> len(empty)
0
>>> len(singleton)
1
>>> singleton
('hello',)
```

Following this I ran following snippet,

```
>>> foo=1,2,3,
>>> len(foo)
3
>>> foo
(1, 2, 3)
```

Why does `singleton` prints with an trailing comma `,` where as `foo` seems to trim it ?

Comment: To consider a single element as a tuple but not as just an element, you need a comma at the end.

Comment: Simply because `('hello')` wouldn't be a tuple.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the syntax rule for having trailing commas in tuple definitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992559/what-is-the-syntax-rule-for-having-trailing-commas-in-tuple-definitions)

Comment: yes that I understand but shouldn't the python interpreter should automatically trim the trailing comma and print ('hello'), since enclosing parenthesis are enough to determine that its a tuple, not a string otherwise

Comment: @Wouterr, the question is closely related but I am more concerned about reasoning as of why the printing of tuple is inconsistent.

Answer (score 4):

Beacause `("Hello")` is not a tuple, it is same as `"Hello"`.

```
>>> ("Hello")
'Hello'
```

in order to distinguish `tuple` with single element from a simple expression in `()` a `,` is necessary. Whereas `(1,2,3)` is clearly a collection of items, and as they are enclosed by `()` it can easily be inferred as a `tuple`, hence no need for a trailing `,`.

Answer (score 0):

because you define variable"singleton" as ("hello",), you don't need comma  to end it, and for "foo", you define it, so it shows as what you defined