# Why the result of the function is different when one argument used in args?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, args

When I pass 1 argument in args it returns/prints argument and comma in the tuple. But why doesn't add a comma after 2 arguments or more?

```
def print_args(*args):
    print(args)

#If arguments are more than one or zero:

print_args(1,2,3)  #Out: (1,2,3)
print_args(1,2)    #Out: (1,2)
print_args()       #Out: ()

#If I pass 1 argurment:

print_args(1)      #Out: (1,)  ?
print_args("a")    #Out: ('a',)?
print_args([])     #Out: ([],) ?

#Using return statement instead of print():

def return_args(*args):
    return args

return_args(1,2) #Out: (1, 2)
return_args(1) #Out: (1,)
```

Comment: Not a strict duplicate, but this is closely related to [What is the syntax rule for having trailing commas in tuple definitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7992559/364696)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding parentheses around a single item is the same as redundant grouping, and does not create the object as a tuple. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences):

> A special problem is the construction of tuples containing 0 or 1
> items: the syntax has some extra quirks to accommodate these. Empty
> tuples are constructed by an empty pair of parentheses; a tuple with
> one item is constructed by following a value with a comma (it is not
> sufficient to enclose a single value in parentheses).

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) close with commenting that this implementation is indeed, "Ugly, but effective."