# what defines an empty array in python?

Tags: python, numpy

If I load data, and ask

np.shape(data)

and the answer is (somenumber,) with no entry after the comma, does this mean the array is empty?

For instance, (151234,).

In this particular case, I am loading in a large dataset (5 GB) of pickled data, but I believe the array is empty.

Googled python empty array,

Comment: no it just means it only has one dimension

Comment: Related / possible duplicate: [What is the syntax rule for having trailing commas in tuple definitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7992559/11082165), plus the fact that a tuple's `repr` is intended to be a valid tuple literal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`np.shape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.shape.html) returns the shape of the array as a `tuple` of `int`s. `(151234,)` is simply a tuple with a single element.

A shape of `(151234,)` means that the array has one dimension, and that dimension has a size of `151234`. It is not an empty array. An empty array would have a size of `0` along at least one of its dimensions.