# 2.7.6 python version needs parenthesis to print?

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing, version

Is it normal for me to use parenthesis when making a call to print in Python 2.7? I thought only 3 onwards needs to do this?

without the parenthesis I get a syntax error.

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

but with parenthesis, it works.

I was under the assumption that 2.7 doesn't need parenthesis to print?

Comment: Have you used `from __future__ import print_function`?

Comment: I am using from __future__ import print_function, would that be it?

Comment: So *why* are you using `from __future__ import print_function`?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6182964/145400, right?

Comment: And see https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print

Comment: I inherit some code and was unsure what was causing it

Comment: Very related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560804/why-do-we-invoke-print-after-importing-print-function-in-python-2-6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your impression is correct, it's not needed (unless of course you `import print_function` von `__future__`!). However, it's not prohibited either. `print` is followed by an expression, and `(sys.version)` is a valid expression as much as `sys.version` is. Note that `(x)` does not create a tuple containing `x` (that would be `(x,)`).