# Importing Axes3D changes the way add_subplot behaves - is this a namespace violation?

Tags: python, matplotlib

This has always been a source of confusion for me: importing `Axes3D` (just some sort of python object for our purposes here) appears to change an unrelated function, `add_subplot`, from a different module. How can that happen? Doesn't that violate the whole idea of namespaces?

What I mean is:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> f = plt.figure()
>>> ax = f.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
# Fails with ValueError: Unknown projection '3d'
>>> from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
>>> ax = f.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
# Works!
```

At first I thought it was similar to `from __future__ import print_function`, which then somehow magically introduces a function called `print` into the namespace. But [as it turns out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560804/why-do-we-invoke-print-after-importing-print-function-in-python-2-6), that *is* in fact magic, and is specific to the `__future__` module.

So, how does Axes3D work?

Comment: It looks like [_monkey patching_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-a-monkey-patch) to me... that is the initialization of the `Axes3D` module injects their code into into the target classes.

Comment: @rodrigo Is that really a pythonic way of doing things? Ideally, I'd like to be able to make out what's going on when I read the import statements: I import a module that has some functions and classes (which in turn could support more functions), etc... I then use those functions in my code. And this enables me to go back and introspect those modules' internals.

Comment: Okay, so it *is* [thought to be evil](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5626255/525169)...

Comment: Maybe it is not the most Pythoning thing, but hey, it gets the work done. Although personally, in your example I'd just use free functions.